# apache2 terminated after SSH logged out UBUNTU

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-18.04

I have Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS running Apache/2.4.29 server , I have the following users:

Ubuntu
bagy
weeby

whenever I logged in to the server as Weeby users using SSH, after logged out, the web-server and apache2 goes down

I have tried multiple solutions. I added Weeby to sudo group but it is still

I would like to keep apache2 running even after SSH logging out

Comment: How do you start apache?

Comment: Also, what is in the system logs and apache logs?

Comment: Have you tried `screen` ?

Comment: Hi @RomeoNinov
I'm starting apache as a root user

Comment: Hi @NikitaKipriyanov

the apache error logs show:

[Fri Dec 10 09:36:48.930894 2021] [core:alert] [pid 6257] AH00050: Child 6263 returned a Fatal error... Apache is exiting!
[Fri Dec 10 09:36:48.931006 2021] [:emerg] [pid 6257] AH02818: MPM run failed, exiting

Comment: @MansourWbss, not with which user, but how, which command do you execute?

Comment: @RomeoNinov
Hi ,, the command was: sudo service apache2 restart nohup

Comment: @RomeoNinov 

Hi.. it appears that is was issue with Mutex files , I had to uncomment Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default and set it to default